# adapting d3 sequences sunburst example to new data & getting js error

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm attempting to repurpose [the sequences sunburst example](http://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426) from the d3 gallery, and am getting no viz + a js error that I don't know how to fix.

"My" code can be found [here](https://github.com/rpardee/d3_sunburst_error).  My sole change from the original (pretty much) is using my own (right now fake) data, to depict what happens to patients who are smokers & come in to see the doc.  They can discuss both smoking cessation, and lung cancer screening, each of which have their own distinct pipelines.

The error comes from the `buildHierarchy()` function in sequences.js.  This guy consumes the original sample data provided w/the sample just fine (provided in that repo as 'sample-data.csv'--change line 46 of sequences.js to switch over to that).  But when I point it at [my little fake dataset](https://github.com/rpardee/d3_sunburst_error/blob/master/event-sequences.csv), it barfs with a:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined sequences.js:303
```

I've stepped through that function & can see that it happens after that function goes to add a leaf node for the last component of the first line in the csv. At that point in the execution, `children` is not set, and so the call to `push()` on it fails.

I don't understand why the original data does not also cause this problem, or how to fix `buildHierarchy()` so it will work.

Any help gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix it, ran into a similar problem with this for some datasets. Just added the children:[] when creating a new child node. Also it will look slightly wrong unless you add an "-End" to the one element data bits (DiscussScreening and DiscussedCessation) like how the example has Product>End

```
function buildHierarchy(csv) {
    var root = {
        "name": "root",
        "children": []
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < csv.length; i++) {
        var sequence = csv[i][0];
        var size = +csv[i][1];
        if (isNaN(size)) { // e.g. if this is a header row
            continue;
        }
        var parts = sequence.split("-");
        var currentNode = root;
        for (var j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
            var children = currentNode["children"];
            var nodeName = parts[j];
            var childNode;
            if (j + 1 < parts.length) {
                // Not yet at the end of the sequence; move down the tree.
                var foundChild = false;
                for (var k = 0; k < children.length; k++) {
                    if (children[k]["name"] == nodeName) {
                        childNode = children[k];
                        foundChild = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // If we don't already have a child node for this branch, create it.
                if (!foundChild) {
                    childNode = {
                        "name": nodeName,
                        "children": []
                    };
                    children.push(childNode);
                }
                currentNode = childNode;
            } else {
                // Reached the end of the sequence; create a leaf node.
                childNode = {
                    "name": nodeName,
                    "size": size,
                    "children" : []
                };
                children.push(childNode);
            }
        }
    }
    return root;
};
```

Comment: Lovely--thank you!  I had not noticed the -end elements in the original data.  Interestingly, if I add one to every line, then I needn't change the js at all.